# Inserting search terms into a search input in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, search

When using Drupal 7, how do I print the current search terms into a search form in a block?

In Drupal 6, I used something like this in my template.php:

```
$vars['search_keys'] = search_get_keys();
```

Then, in search-theme-form.tpl.php I had:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php print $search_keys; ?> name="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form-1">
```

But search_get_keys doesn't exist in Drupal 7, so I can't use this method.

Using arg(2) is the only method I've come up with, but that seems a little hacky, because it will break if the URL ever changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using **Apache Solr** (http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) you can use

```
$query->getParam("q")
```

in your search-result.tpl.php template.

Otherwise, you can use the slightly modified version of the function above:

```
function get_current_search_terms() {
// only do this once per request
static $return;
    if (!isset($return)) {
        // extract keys from path
        $path = explode('/', $_GET['q'], 3);
        // only if the path is search (if you have a different search url, please modify)
        if(count($path) == 3 && $path[0]=="search") {
            $return = $path[2];
        } else {
            $keys = empty($_REQUEST['keys']) ? '' : $_REQUEST['keys'];
            $return = $keys;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

edit: no need for check_plain here

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've come up with:

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_search_block_form(&$vars) {

  $path_args = arg();

  // Insert the current search term (if applicable).
  $value = (count($path_args) == 3 && (strpos($path_args[0], 'search') !== false)) ? filter_xss($path_args[2]) : '';

  $vars['search_form'] = str_replace('value=""', 'value="' . $value . '"', $vars['search_form']);

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?